Why isn't schematic symbol controlling comment visibility?
I'm trying to update my libraries to have all the comments, etc., show when I'd like them to.
In the schematic symbol, I have chosen to 'Hide' the comment field for components like resistors, while having it 'Shown' for IC's and other components. For some reason, the schematic is ONLY listening to the setting in the Tools -> Preferences > Schematic > Defaults > Comment 'Show' vs 'Hide' (eyeball checkbox).
It does not seem to matter whether or not I have the 'Override Library Primitive', all of my components are following the visibility of the schematic setting rather than of their specific schematic symbol. In the example below, you can see the 'Comment' is hidden, but once placed, the comment is visible with 'RES, 0.01'
This feels like a bug, but I'd like to make sure


This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).
